# org.acra.CrashReportDialog not found

Tags: android, android-activity, acra

I found this wonderful library https://github.com/ACRA/acra for Crash Report Tracking.
I have imported the jar file into my project and added the ACRA.init to my current application.

```
public class AppController extends Application {
.......
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
    ACRA.init(this);
}

<application
        android:name="com.mobiledev.Synergy.control.AppController"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

And every time I run the app I get this error.

```
STACK_TRACE=android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.mobiledev.Synergy/org.acra.CrashReportDialog}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1556)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1054)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1043)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:283)
at org.acra.ErrorReporter.notifyDialog(ErrorReporter.java:757)
at org.acra.ErrorReporter$4.run(ErrorReporter.java:732)
```

I guess I need to include the CrashReportDialog Activity from the acra jar files. But how should I do it?
Thanks guys,

Comment: Post your entire AndroidManifest. @Sam's answer is correct.

Comment: Hi William, every thing is working now, I did apply the answer of Sam but at first it was not working then I tried to compile the project and clean. Also restarted my application. Its now working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following xml code in your manifest file

```
<activity android:name="org.acra.CrashReportDialog"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" />
```

Comment: hi sam, I already did that but same error is showing. it cant find the org.acra.CrashReportDialog. Is there something I missed setting up the jar file?. I've read about adding the jar to build path but I cant find it in my Intellij.

Comment: Make sure you're using at least v4.3 of ACRA - see https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#dialog . In case it helps, in my app's `build.gradle` file, I have this in the `dependencies` section: `compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.7.0'`

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the exact same issue and resolved it like this:

- go to the libs folder where the jar is located
- try to delete the jar (with safe usage search)
  (Android studio will ask confirmation whether you want to delete the entry in the:

```
 (workspaceroot)\(yourapppath)\build.gradle
```

file

- you want to replace the

```
compile files('libs/acra-4.(version).jar')
```

with

```
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.7.0'
```

- sync gradle (there is a link in the upper right corner of the gradle file your editing)
- try to delete the jar again (required) (it should succeed now)
- run your app and let the acra magic shine...

Regards,

S.